# using two dependent modules at the same time?

Tags: angularjs

How can I use [ngRoute] and [ngResource] at the same time.

Not sure if I am right but 
I've got my code looking something like this

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",  ["ngRoute"],["ngResources"]);
```

But this doesn't work

Originally it is something like this

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp",  ["ngRoute"]);
```

I want to add ngResource to add the API restful post on my site.

Any help or suggestions please.
Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First thing they aren't directive, they are angular `module`*. You should mention all the dependencies inside the array itself, it contains collection of all the dependent modules.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [
   "ngRoute",
   "ngResource"
   //,...other dependent module should be kept in array as comma separated.
]);
```

Comment: Hey this is not working for me !!!

Comment: @BinayDhawa hey I had `,` after `"ngResource"` try now.. I removed it, It should work

Comment: Hey Pankaj,
figured out the problem was using **ngResources** intead of **ngResource**
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Oh man.. i shouldn't have missed it..

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",  ["ngRoute","ngResources"]);
```

the second argument of `angular.module` is an array, and you are passing **two** arrays. Rather, pass every module as a `string` in the same array. **They are not directives but modules**